# Table cell borders do not show

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

[image: No borders showing]

The above image shows my problem - the cells in the image are meant to have a single pixel red border round each of them, yet only one top border is showing.

I have an `invalid` class for table cells which has the following CSS:

```css
th.invalid, td.invalid {
    border: 1px double #b8202a;
}
```

Using the Chrome debugger, I can see the class applied to the cell, and I can also see that the layout states that th cell should have the specified border yet it does not consistently have red borders.
Increasing the border size or type between double and solid seems to have no effect. Hovering over the cell reveals the borders are there without color.

What am I likely to be doing wrong? :-)

**Update**: Thanks for your input. The information in this [border color with border-collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096390/table-border-color-in-css-with-border-collapse) is probably relevant to the reason why it has issues.

Comment: Its hard to tell without more code, can you post a self contained example in your question or a jsfiddle.net of the behaviour?

Comment: I have a suspicion I won't be able to replicate it in jsFiddle

Comment: Just use the dom inspector from your chrome developer tools (F12) and look which classes overwrite this one...

Comment: I have done and it doesn't reveal anything overrwriting it. I have added an image to show the problem

Comment: can you give us som more information about the styling of the table, especially th other cells?

Comment: Have you got (a derivation of): `table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}`

Comment: The cell styling is mainly Bootstrap and Datatables standard

Comment: @SW4 yes - I thought this meant the cell borders just had no separation. If you expand on your question you may have the answer :-)

Comment: come on, we need details to help you, not vague information...
Something Like this http://fiddle.jshell.net/b3wbq/ might have happend.

Comment: @vogomatix - not sure I follow?

Comment: I would just try to **!important** it to see if it works or is there still something overwriting it. But as the others before me said, it's hard to answer without knowing if there is something overwriting it or not.

Comment: @SW4 I thought from your border-collapse query that you had an idea what the problem is.

Comment: The fiddle I posted is based on the idea of @SW4.

Comment: Please don't blindly suggest `!important`. It just makes style sheets more confusing and is usually a symptom of badly structured HTML or CSS that should be corrected instead.

Comment: @Daniel (and SW4): I am sorry I cannot post more information but you guys have given me some leads to look into. Thanks

Comment: The style `double` can't have effect unless the border is at least 3px wide.

Comment: I am not a fan of `!important` either. Checking the effect of `border-collapse` and `spacing` looks more promising

Comment: @RoToRa as I mentioned I tried increasing the border size/style in Chrome debugger.

Comment: @RoTaRa the double styling is an attempt to increase the priority of the style - double takes precedence over solid in some browsers.

Answer (score 6):

> SOLVED

Hi,

I had the same case while using bootstrap 3.

The issue I found was the bootstrap's css property:

```
table {    
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse; /* here is the devil */  
}
```

I did overwrite it in my own css by:

```
table,
table td {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-collapse: separate; /* This line */
}
```

Then it worked..!

Answer (score 2):

You probably have some bug in CSS, here's a quick example <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/GCCT8/)**</kbd>

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="invalid">Text</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="invalid">Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

```
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th.invalid,
td.invalid {
  border: 1px double #b8202a;
}
```

but if you want single pixel border maybe you should use

```
th.invalid,
td.invalid {
  border: 1px solid #b8202a;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned, I've tried combinations of border widths and types. Your jsfiddle renders fine in my browser, but I can see that it is possible the browser may have issues if border-collapse is in effect and I'll look into that. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try add !important below code

```
th.invalid, td.invalid {
border: 1px double #b8202a !important;
}
table.invalid
 border: 1px double #b8202a !important; 
}
tr.invalid
{
border: 1px double #b8202a !important;
}
```

See the below link for [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RWA7p/)

Thanks 
Maha

Comment: Or you could, you know - add more CSS specificity and not use the !important tag. Sigh.

Comment: Agreed I don't like using `!important` either. However, it is perhaps useful in finding out if the issue resolves itself by its use