# Border bottom of top row is hiding the border property of 2nd row

Tags: html, angular, css, sass

I am facing one problem with table row border styles.

Suppose, I have 2 rows in a table.

1st row has `border-bottom: 0.2rem solid #F1F2F2`.

2nd row I want to highlight with `border: 1px solid red` based on some condition to highlight the row using `[ngClass]` property.

**Actual Result** is 2nd is highlighted with 3 sides (left, right and bottom) but not top as 1st row's border-bottom making it to hide.

**Expected**: Should highlight all sides of the row.

Please look below image for the problem I'm facing

CSS:

```
.table__row {
    border-bottom: 0.2rem solid #F1F2F2;
}
.tr-outline {
   boder: 1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

`<tbody class="table__body">
        <tr class="table__row" *ngFor="let item of entries" [ngClass]="{'tr-outline': highlightRow(item.isHighlight)}">
           <td class="td-name">{{ item.name}}</td>
           <td class="td-cif">{{item.id}}</td>
           <td class="td-icon">{{item.excercise}}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>`

[Table row style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W06yU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your border to td elements because your table element have set border-collapse: collapse property

[table-border-color-in-css-with-border-collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096390/table-border-color-in-css-with-border-collapse)

Comment: Thanks man!! it worked but had to change the application's common css table property