# How to change table header border color and size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/content/tables/#overview

How can I override and modify the bootstrap 5 `table` border below the headline?

I want to achieve this with simple CSS override, not using SASS.

I tried the following, which did not have any effect:

```
.table > thead > tr > th {
    border-bottom-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: This is because of the `border-collapse`, Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096390/table-border-color-in-css-with-border-collapse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing around with it a bit, for some reason, I was only able to override the existing style by specifying the whole `border-bottom` property, with width, style, and color, with the width a minimum of `2px`. I was also able to get the selector simplified, and remove the `!important`.

```css
.table thead th {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-uWxY/CJNBR+1zjPWmfnSnVxwRheevXITnMqoEIeG1LJrdI0GlVs/9cVSyPYXdcSF" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Last</th>
      <th>Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Heretic</td>
      <td>Monkey</td>
      <td>Heretic Monkey</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/35342

Here is the CSS that can remove the border

```
.table > :not(:first-child) {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

Then you can apply your own styling

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed "border-bottom: 1px" not work problem

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of solutions you can try.

**Solution 1.**

```
.table > :not(:first-child) {
border-top: 0;
}
```

Take a look at [this github issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/35342)

**Solution 2.**

other one is add **table-borderless** class to the table as given below

```
<table class="table table-dark table-borderless">
  ...
</table>
```

then you can give your custom border classes to that table.

e.g.

```
#myTable table,
thead,
tbody,
tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
}
```

actually in my case 1st solutions didn't worked but by using 2nd one I am able to apply my custom border css.

Hope this will also useful for someone.